# Light passing through object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCf2Y.png) ,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjqcI.png)

I created this scene and added kind of a second floor but now the light form the pointlights underneath is passing through the floor and i have no clue how to fix it. Any advice?Those are the pictures of my scene in unity ;
Edit:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5C7n.png)

Comment: Show us inspector view of Renderer and Material of the object that is passing light while it shouldn't instead of two black pictures that tell nothing :)

But I suppose you have Cast Shadows = Off in renderer (try different options). If that's not the case try different shader in your material.

Comment: Cast shadows are on and i changed the shaders around a bit. I also tried switching the lighting settings but nothing helped. A screenshot of the material is in the original question  as an edit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.